# Fewest dice rolling as dice rolling

Tags: code-golf

[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255460/)

Now you have some dice which you may roll several times. You need a uniform random integer between 1 and \$n\$, inclusive. Show a method that rolls the fewest times and behaves as an \$n\$-sided dice.

Alternative question: Given a set \$S\$ and \$n\$, pick the fewest elements from \$S\$(each element can be picked multiple times), such that their product is a multiple of \$n\$.

Output some unambigious constant or crash (but not infinite loop) if it's impossible.

Test cases:

```
S, n => possible result
{6}, 9 => {6,6}
{2,3}, 12 => {2,2,3}
{2,8}, 4 => {8}
{6}, 1 => {}
{2}, 6 => -1
{12,18}, 216 => {12,18}
{12,18}, 144 => {12,12}
{18}, 144 => {18,18,18,18}
```

Shortest code in each language wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/233790/adaptive-randomisation)

Comment: @emanresuA Not that related. This only allow finite rolling

Comment: Why can’t 3 twos solve {2}, 6?

Comment: @Jonah If it results 7 or 8 you don't get random integer in 1..6

Comment: I get it, sorry I misread before

Comment: Every valid solution is doing `for(i=0..n)for(x in S^i)if(prod(x)%n==0)return x`

Comment: 05AB1E would likely do `shortest(x in (S*n)^i if prod(x)%n==0)`, which is at least different

Comment: Can I assume that `S` does not contain `1`?

Comment: @matteo_c Maybe no if we have needed a 1-face dice, we may have one

Comment: Claim if u use this assumption though

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 104 bytes

Expects `(S)(n)`. Returns either a string such as `"2*2*3"` or *false* if there's no solution.

```javascript
(a,N=0)=>F=n=>(g=(b,q=N)=>q&&b.some(s=>eval((o=s)||1)%n<1|g(a.map(v=>s?s+'*'+v:v),q-1)))``?o:N++<n&&F(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/fToMwFAbwe59iN7JzpDBPJQSWld3tkhcwJusmIxrWDmt6Izw7tm5mf9CmV19@@b72XVppth9vh89I6ddq2IkBJCvFI4piJZQooBawYa0oXdAGwSY2el@BEUVlZQOghcGuI7xXC@pqkPFeHsCKwixNOH2YhnZukbURIeJ6vdTzMgwXKghWoHDYamV0U8WNrmEHz@kLQo44OZ7ZbPKVsrS/u1GcPTlH/Ai94sxlf7jMueTU5102Mn6RrhbHNY6klySiW0Kckd/i5KFv@Un6/xwlyYXjY3dGp1dRxn7v@A8sdzyjs85Z3g/f)

Comment: [Fail](https://tio.run/##RcpBDoIwEEDR01hmBJp0Y9Qw9SDGhIKl0UCHOqYr7l7ZufvJ@2@XnYyf1/ptIz99mag4spEsBIKhSRSR7KCFFw9C1mc3AzAJbpvBQ@zMHkmp/xHA6cWtkMnKTerqWNX5mrFJrUHEvleKy8hRePZ65gAT3E/N5YFw3r38AA)

Comment: @l4m2 Not a great fix, but it should be OK now.

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 76 bytes

```javascript
s=>g=(t,[p,...r]=[1],...a)=>p%t?!r[t]&&g(t,...a,...s.map(v=>[p*v,...r,v])):r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc3RCoMgFAbg@z1Fu1joODN0IW3D9iDihbSKjZai0eu3HAmjGMhB/v87nJceta/c0w6n3jzqqRGTF2Ur0ADSAiHEKSGpCj@NRWkPw33v5KDStJ1JSMPw5K0tGkUp7XH8bsGoML66qTK9N11NOtOiBkmuMLpgfEuyLJEcuNqtAIPzTCiLhkFItqqYVR5RsQHhDo31dn1u@dI2uvP1GlAGNFxgNLIl@gdpnv9CtoVrVUB8avoA)

```javascript
s=> // set of dices
  g=(
  t, // target point
  [p, // product of currently selected dices
   ...r // array of currently selected dices
  ]=[1], // initially, we do not select any dices, and the product is 1
  ...a // any other candidate selections
)=>
  p%t? // if current select is invalid
    !r[t]&& // if we already used more than `t` dices
            // we know we cannot get `t` with current set
            // return `false`
    g(t,...a,...s.map(v=>[p*v,...r,v])): // for each candidate dice
                                         // try it recursively
  r // return current selected dices
```

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 86 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,t,p=1,r=[],*a:t<len(r)or p%t and f(s,t,*sum([(p*i,r+[i])for i in s],a))or r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCsIwEADvvmJBhKTuJWkpVewvvIUcIm0x0KYhTQ@@vjZGbUTYy87Mrn34@2jyZenqXg23RsGEHm3N0NVCYqbO/tK3hjg6OrAHD8o00JEQZdM8EEFsptEdhZa0WxMN2sAkUdFw4BbrtPGkI6KUCCdKYQ@ixFLuvoJjvirGo@MY9tRWqy2irBIR/rGI03yl5Yte3dxunHFk4RFn0b7Bf8CKYgt4GvzaCj8jlyc)

Just a port to Python. Or [84 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc1NCoMwEAXgvacIlEJiZ9FEEVtqT9FdmIWlSgMaQ4yLnj41tT8RCrOZ9z1mzMPdB51531Zd3V9vNRnBgak42EoipPXRnbpGU8sGKy20NHA6Tj2V1KQK7E4qZO1giSJKkxGhZgyl2brzHr2xSjvaUlkgkANjZENkAQUmm68IyGbjYkEBYU8iLWfNFywjCAf5Esf1OS1e6cVOTfSFC@DhkuALv4M/DZ7nv4ZYNdZcwmfQPwE) but very slow...

Comment: Python answer `f` not defined

Comment: How do `sum([(p*i,r+[i])for i in s],a)` work?

Comment: @l4m2 should be fixed. The `sum(x, y)` is "reduce (left fold) x with operator `+` with initial value y" something like `x.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,y)` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>16</s> 11 bytes

```
hf!%*FTQy*E
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyNNUVXLLSSwUsv1/39LrmizWAA)

Takes n and S in that order. Outputs a list or throws an index error if there is no solution.

#### Explanation

We simply check all possible combinations of elements from \$S\$ up to \$n-1\$ elements (as well as many other pointless longer ones) and take the shortest one which works. Saved 5 bytes thanks to [@Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256606/73054)'s trick of using the powerset of input list repeated, however this comes at the cost of being even slower. This times out for large \$n\$, but can be made much better by adding a logarithm to that range as seen [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyNNUVXLLSSwUstVzzXn/39LrmizWAA), at the cost of a few bytes.

```
hf!%*FTQy*EQ    # implicitly add Q
                # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
         *EQ    # repeat the second eval(input()) Q times
        y       # powerset
 f              # filter on lambda T
    *FT         #   multiply all elements of T (or 1 for empty list)
   %   Q        #   modulo by Q
  !             #   not (will be true for 0)
h               # first element (will be the shortest list, or will raise an index error if there are none)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṁ`, 12 bytes

```
(⁰n↔≬Π¹Ḋc:[X
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuYAiLCIiLCIo4oGwbuKGlOKJrM6gwrnhuIpjOltYIiwiIiwiNDhcblsxMiwxNl0iXQ==)

Half port of the pyth answer in that it checks all combinations of length 0 to n-1. Returns 0 for invalid, otherwise the list.

### Explained

```
(⁰n↔≬Π¹Ḋc:[X
(             # For N in range(0, n):
 ⁰n↔          #   get all combinations of S of length N
    ≬   c     #   find the first combination where
     Π        #     the product
      ¹Ḋ      #     is divisible by n
         :[X  #   if it's non-empty break from the loop
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
иæé.ΔP¹Ö
```

Will output `-1` if no result can be found.

The larger \$n\times L_S\$ (where \$L_S\$ is the length of set \$S\$), the slower it is.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//9C4w6bDqS7OlFDCucOW//80Cls3LDksMTEsMTMsMThd) or [verify most test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/X94bVllgr2SQmJeioKSPZDxqG0SkFGZcGjl/ws7Di87vFLv3JSAQ@sOT/tfq/M/OtpSJ9osNlZHIdpEJ9pIxwLMNISJmQHFwAwjHaCgsY6pjrmOpY6hAUwDmGeoY2isYwjUGQsA). (The test cases that time out have been ommitted.)

**Explanation:**

```python
и         # Repeat the second (implicit) input-list the first (implicit) input-integer
          # amount of times as single flattened list
 æ        # Get the powerset of this list
  é       # Sort it by length (shortest to longest)
   .Δ     # Find the first list that's truthy for (or -1 if none are):
     P    #  Take the product of the list
      ¹Ö  #  Check whether it's divisible by the first input-integer
          # (after which the found result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Fail `2
[7,9,10]`

Comment: @l4m2 Thanks for noticing! Should be fixed now at the cost of 2 bytes.

Comment: Fail `4
[7,9,11,13,18]`

Comment: @l4m2 Woops.. Fixed and saved 2 bytes at the same time, so I'm back at 8 bytes. The extend builtin wasn't the way to go..

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <strike>135</strike> 134 bytes

```python
lambda s,n:[x for i in range(n)for x in combinations_with_replacement(s,i)if not math.prod(x)%n][0]
from itertools import*
import math
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY_PSgMxEMbv-xQDIiQlFbOW0hZ8knUpaZu4gc1MyEZcEa--hJcFUXwl38aku9QeOpfh-8188-fj27_EhnD4NPcPX0_RzFe_761yu4OCTuCm6sFQAAsWISh81Ax5Bn0Ge3I7iypawm77bGOzDdq3aq-dxsg6Ybk1gBTBqdjc-EAH1vNrrKvbujCBHNioQyRqO7DOU4izYsxHw3TNT17n87qqgBTsdfkmYM3FpEoBdwnI8pysElmcQDbISV3lhqSXp6pM_TIbSnkBysX_nDNQb47MB5s-NWzmOR_vHYYx_wE)

Works like the Pyth answer

-1 thanks to [@corvus_192](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46901/corvus-192)

Comment: -1 byte: `import math` and `math.prod`

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 42 bytes

```
¿¬﹪ＸΠθηη«⊞υ⟦⟧Ｗ⬤υ﹪Πκη≔ΣＥυＥθ⁺κ⟦μ⟧υ⭆¹⌊Φυ¬﹪Πλη
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY_BisJADIbP9imCpxRGqIKr0JMXb5UBj2UOtat2MO3YzowexCfZi4cV977Psod9G1OtYCCEhO__k3z95EXW5Cajy-Xq3WYw_f_TG8CFcZiYT08GpTmuG5QNd7nDOhRQPDIM4RT0pLcFegGpCuOgdyw0rQFnRO3sZdBJdy_ZzFq9rXDpS0yy_YPkUguQ5C3u2KxUzAnwradsdOVw6bhsW27IuK50yeq5Jse3scH7vd066tZxxMH5265y2714S_uDA_XVb5p-CBhGnGMlYDSJIvUk7g) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs nothing if no solution exists but `[]` for an input of `1`. Explanation:

```
¿¬﹪ＸΠθηη«
```

Check that a solution exists.

```
⊞υ⟦⟧
```

Start with all possible results of length `0`.

```
Ｗ⬤υ﹪Πκη
```

While none of the results work...

```
≔ΣＥυＥθ⁺κ⟦μ⟧υ
```

... form the Cartesian product of the results with the input list.

```
⭆¹⊟Φυ¬﹪Πλη
```

Pretty-print the first working result.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 150 bytes

```c
int*f(s,k,n,p,v,w)int*s,*v,*w;{for(v=calloc(n,4);p=1;){for(w=v;*w;)p*=s[*w++-1];if(p%n<1){for(w=v;*w;)*w++=s[*w-1];return v;}for(w=v;++*w>k;)*w++=0;}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZFNbtswEIWRpXSKiQMHpEQHpmsYSWjlIq6RqrJUE1IpQdQPEEPX6KYbb3KirpzTZEaKWqcwQEHDmW_mPZK_X6PnH1F0PL7WVTK7P_3SpvISZkUqjChEI1pOGSu8RnitOiR5yZogCrMsj5gRS66KQCre59ugUcjwwgvsxmt9fya3SiesmJq1_IxQtYcIKeOqLg00qhsR3_fap_QDm6uuG9y9Xf250SbK6l0Ma1vtdH63f3JdNAg_Q20Yh4PrRPuwhEybeCPn861ynXavsxiY7KsOwUZAKsCzivYJMBuFJmGT6Q6mu4mAW6zfphyCAGaSI-N8L-MwJdpCAB-HxwlWv8R5wnAk51RF-0A70Gga9DpV4Puak6zzVwMFLCaJ7_DDVZTYgzVtirp6BDQh4ICYGYdemEkjxz7iaepGb_sOnGLZpJsM7UlW2z3D28rrCjNnepjoBQ8DSSJegwek56cLuqDfoAZcBzA_O9l_NprRRvfPyldz2QwynTu87fH07QEAJMAKf65cAAzri7uEMb535RmzkCtMIikxv1x-iiUGxKwGfkHxIPQO)

Eventually segfaults if the problem is impossible.

Takes O(|S|<sup>n</sup>) time if there is a solution, and Ω(|S|<sup>n</sup>) otherwise. The exponent of such bounds can be lowered to ⌈log<sub>2</sub> n⌉ at the cost of more bytes.

Comment: not infinite loop) if it's impossible.

Comment: You may not need the `int` in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 62 bytes

```hs
s#n=head[o|i<-[0..n],o<-mapM id(s<$[1..i]),mod(product o)n==0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCoQgFADQqwS2KPhJVsQM6BE6wecvZAySya9ks@vujqv3Dpu/@3mWkgWbY7cO4@P1gKOUTBD1EGzaGu@6rFtUUnrqIUTXpSu63@duYs/GjFSC9WzS5fluEdWLhFoWwAnmuqmmArjCm8S8UvkD)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 66 bytes

```hs
s#n=head[o|i<-[0..n],o<-sequence.replicate i$s,mod(product o)n==0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLCsMgEADQqwTMooWJ5EdoIZ5kcCE6EKkZrZpd726zeu8w5UMhtFYEq4OMw/jz@4CjlKwh7kOh70VsSWZKwVtTqfN9gTO6R8rRXbZ28clKjbqdxrNK2XPtEaeXFtO6As6w3Jvv3ABu8NZi2XT7Aw)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 91 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
_#1=[]
s#n=let g=gcd n;m=last(sortOn g s)in m:(filter((1<).g)s#div n(g m))
```

greedily includes the dice with maximum greatest common denominator and recurses down target divided by that common denominator on all dice with common denominator, crashes when depleted of feasible dice, generates some too long solutions.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxCsIwEIDhvU9xEIcESiG1g6jZHAUfIBQJtsajyVlyh68fM/3f8H8Cb2tKtWLev0XgFiQMd2Tpnso6P3esyKVVILr4WoAu2aXAornND4IIbJAgn/Ubk6xFa3s1QzSsFvwB6QjZmJoDktsLkhy8t6dZ2Wnq/dgfm8aGlrn@AQ)

Comment: Fail `[6,9]#36`